# Bezier curve with handles using image curved

Tags: curve, bezier

Im trying to draw ( or make illusion of ) curved image like in this post :
[Quadratic Curve with Rope pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32322966/quadratic-curve-with-rope-pattern?noredirect=1&lq=1)

or this one :
[Gradient Stroke Along Curve in Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027087/gradient-stroke-along-curve-in-canvas/24029653#24029653)

in those examples the courve image is static .
but now i like to give the curved image editing options :
using Bezier curve + handlers like in this post .
[Bezier curve with three handles misplaces the control points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378887/bezier-curve-with-three-handles-misplaces-the-control-points)

My Question is:
how can i combine the two ?
That is draw the image to be curved and also be editable using handlers

Comment: I edit the question to be it more clear

Comment: What did you try? Where are you stuck?

Comment: i managed only to do the Bezier curve , translate it to c++ using OpenGL 
with simple drawline command . but i really what to do it with image

Comment: You need to show the code of your approach, as it stands there are too many possible answers: drawing the rope to a texture, tesselating geometry along the curve and texturing it with the rope texture, transform a grid with the rope texture according to the curve in the vertex shader.

Comment: Given your seven year frequenting of Stackoverflow: can you please improve your question by following [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask)? Instead of just links to further posts, show images of what you need (with links if necessary, but have a self-contained question), and show the code you already wrote and where you got stuck?